# How to extract and execute an instruction from a function

Tags: javascript, introspection

Does it exist an elegant way to *'extract'* an instruction from a function passed as a parameter to another one ?

I mean, I have come out with this code but it seems a little bit to simple to return the right value at each execution.

```
var f = function(client){
    client.setText(document.myForm.myName.value);
}

var extractInstruction = function(callBack){
    callBack = callBack.toString()
    var exc = callBack.substring(callBack.indexOf('{') + 1, callBack.lastIndexOf('}'));
    exc = exc.substring(exc.indexOf('(') + 1, exc.lastIndexOf(')'));
    return exc;
}

var test = eval(extractInstruction(f));
```

I've seek into the Reflect documentation but nothing seems to do the work. What if I have several instruction in the *'callback'* function ?

What is important here is to extract the value passed in argument to the client.setText() method.

Comment: why not extract it to an actual function?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: actually write a function that contains the code you want to execute.

Comment: `eval`, `toString` - why? Why not pass a reference to the function directly, similar to: `func = function(){//do whatever}; othermethod(func); othermethod = function(callback){callback()}`

Comment: Why not simply do `f({setText(test) { /* whatever you want to do */})`?

Comment: The programming context is a refactoring. I need to do it because otherwise I will have to edit hundred of classes where there is some code passing a callback function (lets say f) to a standard method used in all the project (lets say extractInstruction). I only need the value of argument passed to the setText() method to rewrite the standard method I'm talking about. I know it seems weird but the actual method have to be rewritten cause the *client* argument of the callback used to be instanciated by a library I need to get rid of.